# dgrid pagination - change i18n language file

Tags: pagination, dgrid

how to load one of the i18n languages library in dgrid pagination?
say I want to load the 'ar' instead of 'en', how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Dojo typically determines the i18n locale to load based on two things:

- The `locale` setting in the `dojoConfig` variable (or `data-dojo-config` attribute of the script tag that loads `dojo.js`), if present
- Otherwise, the locale setting of the browser

If you want to force a locale, overriding `dojoConfig.locale` is usually the way to do it.  This will affect not only dgrid, but all other dojo / dijit i18n resources loaded on the page.

In a script block *before* loading `dojo.js`:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    locale: 'ar'
};
```

*or* in the `dojo.js` script tag:

```
<script src=".../dojo.js" data-dojo-config="locale: 'ar'"></script>
```

The [internationalization tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/i18n/) has more information on overriding this setting and working with i18n resources.

Comment: thanks ken.
this really helps, but although the 'ar' files load but it didn't change the pagination text.

Comment: That is because there currently is no Arabic translation available for dgrid's nls resources.  If you'd be willing to provide one under the [Dojo CLA](http://www.dojofoundation.org/about/cla) (see the other languages' files for reference), you could open a pull request to get one added.

Comment: ok, meanwhile I registered to the CLA but it may take a lot of time until being a committer.
until then, how to run the pagination.js ar file that I added to the "dgrid/extensions/nls/ar" folder?

Comment: If you've added `extensions/nls/ar/pagination.js`, the only other thing you should need to do is add `ar: true` to `extensions/nls/pagination.js` (`dojo/i18n` grabs this root bundle first, which tells it what other bundles are available).  And if you fork the dgrid repo, create a branch, and commit those changes to that branch then pull request it, it shouldn't be a terribly hard thing for us to merge.